# Homepage Django

Tags: python, django

Я запускаю сайт с помощью `localhost` - "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"

файл urls.py проекта

```
# catalog/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path , include



urlpatterns = [
    path('learning_logs/' , include('learning_logs.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls ),
]
```

файл urls.py приложения

```
# catalogs/urls.py
from django.urls import path

from . import views 

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index , name = 'index' )

]
```

файл views.py

```
# catalogs/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render



def index(request):
    """Домашняя(первая) страница"""
    return render(request , 'learning_logs/index.html')
```

также , в папке приложения `learning_logs/` вложена папка `templates/` ,  в которой вложена папка `learning_logs/`, а в ней -  файл `index.html`.Но при этом , когда я захожу на `localhost`  выдается ошибка 404.Хоть я задал страницу `index.html` по умолчанию в `learning_logs.py` >> `path('', views.index , name = 'index' )`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем проблема?

Comment: В том, что вы сделали домашнюю страницу для пути `learning_logs/`, а не для сайта в целом. Если вам этот путь не нужен, то вместо `'learning_logs/'` напишите тоже пустую строку например

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Следуя из этого кода:

```
 # catalog/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path , include



urlpatterns = [
    path('learning_logs/' , include('learning_logs.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls ),
]
```

ваша страница index будет доступна по адресу `127.0.0.1:8000/learning_logs`
если вы хотите сделать доступ к index по пути `127.0.0.1:8000` , то оставьте пустую строку вот здесь `path('' , include('learning_logs.urls')),`